# Creating an object variable out of its meta-object

Tags: java

I have a method (in a class which represent a set of objects) that receive as a parameter a Class object, and I need to find all the objects in the set that have this Class object as their meta-object.

The problem is that i need to return them as an array of their type, and i don't know how to get the objects type.

So in other words, i need to create an array, which his type is depends on the Class object, for example:

```
public Object[] getAllFromType(Class meta){
    Object[] temp = new meta.getDynamicType[fullCells];

    ...
    ...
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `meta` would be and how you would call this. Can you post some more information? You might be able to use generics here depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you also clarify on "all the objects in the set that have this Class object as their meta-object"? Do you mean all instances of the given class in some set, e.g. all `String` instances inside `fullCells`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you've shown you're going to return it as `Object[]` anyway, so you won't get a *compile-time* benefit here, but you can create an array of the right type easily enough:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(meta, fullCells);
```

Note that the cast to `Object[]` is required because `Array.newInstance` returns `Object` - the cast will fail for `int[]` for example, because an `int[]` isn't an `Object[]`. It will work if the array element type is any class or interface type, however.